# How to share the same instance of jQuery across multiple Webpack packs?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, sprockets

I'm working in a Rails app, migrating from Sprockets to Webpack. Our current JavaScript relies on libraries globally assigned to `window`. In order to migrate over, I'd like to maintain global assignment until we address it at a later date. I'd like to swap from Sprockets to Webpack without any JavaScript changes.

We have several JavaScript bundles, which have been manually split up for performance:

- `core.js`, which contains jQuery and a couple other files. It's a blocking bundle.
- `vendor.js`, which contains all other libraries and jQuery plugins. It's a deferred bundle.
- `application.js`, which contains our custom application code. Also a deferred bundle.

All the bundles rely on jQuery, and `application.js` relies on `vendor.js`. That's fine for Sprockets, but is an issue with Webpack.

**How can I keep jQuery in `core.js`, but exclude it from `vendor.js` and `application.js` in Webpack?** or another way to ask this is **How do I share the same *instance* of jQuery across multiple webpack bundles?** I need to use the same instance because `application.js` relies on jQuery plugins defined in `vendor.js`

My config file includes both `expose-loader` and `ProvidePlugin`, but these include jQuery in the bundle itself, which is not the same instance. In other words, I'm getting jQuery bundled multiple times (which is fixed with `splitChunks()`), but I can't guarantee which instance I'm using, therefore can't guarantee the plugin is available.

```js
// Webpacker environment.js config

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.loaders.append('expose', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
    },
    {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: '$'
    }
  ]
});

environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
);


module.exports = environment;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had success with `splitChunks` forcing a single instance for jquery **combined** with the **expose-loader** config like you have described.

Here's the key part of the Webpack config I'm using:

```
environment.splitChunks((config) => {
  return Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: true,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10,
          },
          default: {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
})
```

The key here is to understand that Webpack splitChunks replaces the need for manual code splitting. In other words, let go of the need to explicitly create `core.js` and `vendor.js` packs; consolidate all your imports as part of the `application.js` dependency tree. *Let Webpack do the code-splitting for you.*

Another caveat to mention is that Webpacker's implementation of `splitChunks` means placing a single `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` in the view so that the shared "runtime" chunk will ensure that modules, like jQuery, aren't duplicated.

I used to split my bundles manually like you in my previous projects with Sprockets. When I had to do my own migration to Webpack, it took awhile for this new approach to sink in. I gave a talk about it which will shed some more light on my answer here: https://youtu.be/fKOq5_2qj54?t=185

Comment: Thanks for this and the talk @rossta! `splitChunks` is definitely something we want to use in the future, but it's a little further down the road. Even at that, we may want to keep `core.js` as its own bundle since it's the only blocking JS. We gained roughly 2 seconds of performance by adding `defer: true` to our other bundles and we're not too keen on losing that :)

It seems more and more like I might be looking for [multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations)

Comment: Another way to look at it, in Webpack terms, is the JS you're currently including in `core.js` is your "initial" chunk. Instead of a separate bundle with `defer` for the rest, you can simply use a dynamic import from the initial chunk, e.g. `import('../application')`. In this case, `application.js` would not be a separate pack, i.e. move it out of `app/javascript/packs`; it should instead be an async dependency of your `core.js` pack.

Comment: Put another way, your use case is exactly what `splitChunks` is designed for. You don't want to make explicit bundles but let Webpack do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The only two options that were working in my case were:

**1) Adding jquery to externals like this:**

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
    },
};
```

putting a script tag in a file that you include everywhere (in my case was base.html.twig, and everything else extends from this).

```html
<script src="/path/to/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

**2) Using ProvidePlugin + runtimeChunk: single:**

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            "window.jQuery": 'jquery',
            "window.$": 'jquery',
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
    }
}
```

runtimeChunk single will generate a new file that you have to include in a page that's included everywhere (basically wherever you have an entrypoint you include this runtime chunk !)

Comment: Thank you so much, 2 days of searching and only your solution helped )))

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a solution yet, I've found setting `jQuery` as an external library seems to force a single global instance.

```
// Webpacker environment.js config

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.config.set('externals', {
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jQuery'
});

module.exports = environment;
```

I've been able to test this by using my Sprockets `core.js` bundle and Webpack for the everything else. It all works as expected.

I've posted a follow-up question to try to conditionally set externals and use Webpack for everything: [Conditionally set externals for a specific Webpack bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933900/conditionally-set-externals-for-a-specific-webpack-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is will work, but maybe you could try:

```
# vendor.js

import JQuery from 'jquery' 
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery

// rest of vendor.js code


#application.js
import './vendor.js'

//rest of application.js code
```

Comment: Couldn't seem to get this to work. jQuery was included in both bundles and the instances were different ‍♂️